# plot a heatmap for binary categorical variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, heatmap, categorical-data

I have a dataframe which contains many binary categorical variables, and I would like to display a heatmap-like plot for all the observations, only displaying two colors for "yes" and "no" levels.
I would then like to sort it so that those observations (**ID**) with the most "yes" in their row appear on top.

The sample dataset is provided here:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   var1 = c('yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no'),
                   var2 = c('no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no'),
                   var3 = c('yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes'))
df1


  ID var1 var2 var3
1  1  yes   no  yes
2  2  yes  yes   no
3  3   no   no   no
4  4  yes  yes  yes
5  5   no   no  yes
```

I tried using the `heatmap()` function but I could not make it work. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: to be sure, you want one axis to be `ID`, and the other one to be the different vars ?

Comment: @denis Yes sir, that's the goal, I don't mind displaying the exact **ID**s, but I want each row of the heatmap to belong to one **ID**, and the the vars be displayed as columns.

Comment: Replace yes by 1, no by 0 and launch the following from `library(lattice)` : `levelplot(as.matrix(df1[,-1]))`

Comment: @YacineHajji thanks Yacine, what is this command supposed to do?

Comment: It is going to display a binary color heatmap of your dataframe transformed as a matrix, without the `ID` column for which rownames has the same information

Comment: @YacineHajji but then it displays it as a gradient (as legend), and I cannot sort it as well.

Comment: I geniunly don't get what you want to display. Examples from denis and Ottie answered what you were asking for in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with `heatmap`. Turn the "yes" / "no" columns of your df into a matrix of 0's and 1's and disable some of the defaults such as scaling and ordering.

```
mat1 <- 1*(df1[,-1]=="yes")

> mat1
     var1 var2 var3
[1,]    1    0    1
[2,]    1    1    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1
[5,]    0    0    1

# You only need this step if you want the IDs to be shown beside the plot

rownames(mat1) <- rownames(df1)

> mat1
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    0    1
2    1    1    0
3    0    0    0
4    1    1    1
5    0    0    1

# reorder the matrix by rowSums before plotting

heatmap(mat1[order(rowSums(mat1)),], scale = "none", Rowv = NA, Colv = NA)
```

[image: heatmap outcome]

You can change the colour scheme by specifying the `col` parameter like

```
heatmap(mat1[order(rowSums(mat1)),], scale = "none", Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, col=c("lightgrey", "tomato"))
```

If you would prefer the plot to read left-to-right (one column per ID), just transpose the matrix

```
 heatmap(t(mat1[order(rowSums(mat1)),]), scale = "none", Rowv = NA, Colv = NA)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could display the plot, but some rows are left out. For me, when these rows have the same amount of "yes", this command only displays the first one of them, and omits the rest. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: Please post an example - here, rows with IDs 1 and 2 both have 2 "yes" values, but both are displayed, so I don't think your problem is reproduced.

Comment: I guess since I have many more rows in the original data, the problem is with the margins. For example, if I replicate the same sample data times a random number of rows, then it does not display some rows. I don't know how to adjust the margins though. Will look into it.

Comment: I expect that what you're seeing is that all the rows are plotted, but some row labels are omitted if they don't fit in the plot. `heatmap` is already clever enough to reduce the font size of labels, so your best bet is to increase the size of the output plot, or get rid of the ID labels altogether.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `ggplot`, you need to work in long format. I will use `tidyverse` here:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

df_long <- df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = paste0("var",1:3))

order <- df_long %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  summarise(n = sum(value == "yes"))%>%
  arrange(-n)%>%
  pull(ID)

df_long %>%
  mutate(ID = factor(ID,levels = order))%>%
  ggplot(aes(ID,name,fill = value))+
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

The part with `order` is to have a vector of your ID ordered by their number of yes. You then need to set the levels of the factor variable following this order, in order to have your heatmap ordered by the number of yes.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I don't get the part with `order`, since my goal is to sort based the **ID**s with most `*yes*`es (which ID has the most *yes* across all **var**s), not based on the **var**s.

Comment: ok, I did not get this right. You can do the same, but replacing name by ID. see my edits